# Paypal Express option

Tags: paypal

I'm mulling over using Paypal express as an option for a new ecommerce site. I've searched for an answer to this question but can't seem to find an answer. My question has to do with exactly how you would checkout using Paypal on Etsy, for example. Let's say the total sale price is $20, when the buyer is being redirected back to Etsy after logging on to Paypal so their information can be collected, at what point would Etsy collect their commission? Would Etsy just collect their commission and the remaining payment goes directly to the seller, without Etsy touching the seller's portion? For my site the $20 (for example), needs to go directly to the seller while at the same time my company collects our commission without any part of the sellers portion of the sale being in my Paypal Express account for any amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how they are processing payments.  They could be using Express Checkout with Parallel payments.  Basically when the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call is executed the transaction would be split up into the different accounts.

Comment: How would you input the percentage of the total sale amount that needs to go into either account?

Comment: You would need to calculate the amounts/percentages on your side, and pass over what the amounts are that you are wanting to go into each account.